# Clarification about the measurability of a function

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, metric-spaces

In a book I'm studying, it was stated that:

> let $f:(\Omega,\mathcal A)\to (\Omega',\mathcal A')$ be measurable
> where $\Omega'$ is a semi-metric space with semi-metric $d$, and that
> $\mathcal A'$ is the sigma-algebra spanned by the open balls for this
> semi-metric. If $x\in \Omega'$ is a fixed element, then $d(f,x)$ is measurable.

**Question**. Why is $d(f,x):(\Omega,\mathcal A)\to (\mathbb R,\mathcal B_{\mathbb R})$ measurable?

Should I explore the continuity of $d(f(t),x):\Omega'\to \mathbb R$ ? If it is indeed continous, then the composition $d(\cdot,x)\circ f$ is measurable.

***Def**. $d$ is a semi-metric on some space $\Omega'$ as soon as:

1. $\forall x\in\Omega', d(x,x)=0$;
2. $\forall (x,y,z)\in \Omega'\times\Omega'\times \Omega', d(x,y)\leq d(x,z)+d(z,y)$.

Answer (score 1):

Well, $d(-,x)$ is continuous on $\Omega'$. Indeed, by the triangle inequality,

$$
d(y,x)-d(z,x)\leq d(y,z)
$$
and by symmetry, we get $|d(y,x)-d(z,x)|\leq d(y,z)$ so $d(-,x)$ is actually a contraction. Hence, $d(f,x)$ is a composition of a measurable map with a continuous function and hence, measurable.

Comment: Can you explain the continuity on $\Omega'$? It was stated that $\mathcal A'$ is the sigma-algebra generated by open balls. Why the inverse image of $d(-,x)$ on any open interval should be open in $\Omega'$ w.r.t. the semi-metric $d$?

Comment: From what you've written, $\Omega'$ is the space, and $\mathcal{A'}$ its $\sigma$-algebra. Above is a proof that $d(-,x)$ is a contraction from $\Omega'$ to $\mathbb{R}$. All contractions between semi-metric spaces are continuous. If you don't know this fact, it's a really good exercise to prove it.

Comment: Yes! It was a typo. Thanks I didn't have this result on mind!

Comment: Just a last question. Do you know if that definition of $\mathcal A'$ is really needed?

Comment: @CelineHarumi What do you mean? You need a $\sigma$-algebra on $\Omega'$ in order to talk about measurability. The result that continuous functions are measurable specifically relies on $\mathcal{A}'$ being the Borel-algebra on $\Omega'$.

Comment: I mean, could $\mathcal A'$ be an arbitrary sigma-algebra?

Comment: See the second sentence of my comment.

Comment: What is your definition of a contraction? There, you have assumed that $d$ is the usual metric on $\mathbb R$ which is not the case.

Comment: It would be a contraction if $\lvert d(y,x)-d(z,x) \rvert\leq \lvert y-z\rvert$, isn't it?

Comment: No. If $(M,d)$ and $(M',d')$ are metric spaces, then $f: M\to M'$ is a contraction if $d'(f(x),f(y))\leq d(x,y)$ for all $x,y\in M$.